# Orgchart js error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am writing an organization chart creation program with orgchart.js and simple php. (Without using any framework).
But it gives me the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://uk-s-balkangraph.azurewebsites.net/api/OrgChartJS' from origin 'https://xxxxxx.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I also put the following code in the .htaccess file, but it did not work:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

I also put the following code in the index.php file, but it did not work:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

I am an amateur programmer.
please guide me

Comment: It should be noted that this program works well on localhost

Comment: _"I also put the following code in the .htaccess file"_ - which one? `https://uk-s-balkangraph.azurewebsites.net` is the party that needs to allow for this request to happen here. If you are not in control of _that_ site, then there isn't anything you can do here, other than use a server-side proxy, so that the actual request gets made by that, and not a client that is subject to CORS restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to do it :

1. **Set header instead of add**

Instead of using `header add` you can use `header set`

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

And it's what I will do for next propositions.

2. **Use apache/nginx virtual host configuration**

In VirtualHost config (in apache), you can use :

```
<VirtualHost myhost:80>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

3. **More use PHP header** :

```php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Content-Type');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: I did all this but it didn't work out

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work" ?

Comment: I mean these codes didn't solve my problem. what can i do else for this error?

Comment: You have the exact same error ?

Comment: yes.   Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://fr-balkangraph.azurewebsites.net/api/OrgChartJS' from origin 'https://www.rayansepand.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Do I have to put the second way codes in the httpd.conf file? it's true?